# Asynchronous Google Maps Info Window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

Im trying to put a google map with an info window on my site but need it to load asynchronously. This is the code I am using:

```
function initialize(lat,lng) {

   var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
      zoom:15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI:true
   };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}

function loadScript() {
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
   document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

It is initialized using a click event and printed with html generated via Javascript:

```
...
var lat=40.7127; 
var lng=-74.0059;
..
<div onclick="initialize('+lat+','+lng+');">map</div>
..
html_str += '<div id="googleMap" class="map"></div>';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html_str;
```

The basic map initializes successfully but I am having trouble adding an info window:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content:"Hello World!"
});

infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

I tried placing this code into the initialize() function but no luck. I need help adapting this info window code to my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an infowindow to the map you need to either give it a position or give it an **existing** marker as an anchor.  Best I can see you should be getting a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined`.

If you don't have a marker, set the position of the infowindow:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Hello World!"
});
infowindow.setPosition(map.getCenter());
infowindow.open(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loadScript function invoked by window.onload you have already a callback for initialize. but in this case you haven't the coords assigned. I think in this case initialize fails.

Do the fact you call explicty the initialize function by click you div try a loadScript function  without callback

```
function loadScript() {
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false";
   document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```